# Seagull Diameter Request simulation,

Tags: 4g, diameter-protocol

Can someone please suggest what should be a value of  in the seagull script so that Wireshark correctly decodes MNC-030 and MCC-234?

Comment: What is the relevance of the doxygen tag?

Comment: I found some info about doxygen from http://gull.sourceforge.net/doc/dev/,may be this community can help me with the seagull script. Apologies if I am wrong

Comment: The given link does not work, but doxygen is, in short, a tool to extract documentation from source code, so has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to send the PLMN in the proper format in a Diameter message such as a ULR.  The value has to be entered using the method defined by ETSI.  In your case it would be **0x320430**.  See the example code below.

```
  <command name="ULR">
    <avp name="Session-Id" value="value_is_replaced"></avp>
    <avp name="Vendor-Specific-Application-Id">
        <avp name="Vendor-Id" value="10415"></avp>
        <avp name="Auth-Application-Id" value="16777251"></avp>
    </avp>
    <avp name="Auth-Session-State" value="1"></avp>
    <avp name="Origin-Realm" value="origin.com"></avp>
    <avp name="Origin-Host" value="seagull.origin.com"></avp>
    <avp name="Destination-Realm" value="destination.com"></avp>
    <avp name="User-Name" value="234030123456789"></avp>
    <avp name="RAT-Type" value="1004"></avp>
    <avp name="ULR-Flags" value="34"></avp>
    <avp name="Visited-PLMN-Id" value="0x320430"></avp>
  </command>
```

The ordering of the PLMN digits is outlined in [TS 129 272](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/129200_129299/129272/16.05.00_60/ts_129272v160500p.pdf), section 7.3.9.

Answer (score 1):

Its not related to seagull or any other testing tool.
If you want to find out what should be the value use this:

[image: Visited-PLMN-ID]

Its from the spec: ETSI TS 129 272 V15.6.0